# Bash - command substitution with variables

Tags: bash, variables

I am still new to bash, so I was hoping someone more experience than me would be able to help me. 
I have the following bit of code:

```
DAY1=$(date +"%d/%b/%Y")
DAY2=$(date --date="-1 days" +"%d/%b/%Y")
...
DAY14=$(date --date="-13 days" +"%d/%b/%Y")
COUNT=0
```

What I would like to accomplish is to refer to the substituted commands as something like

```
$DAY($COUNT+1)
```

to produce variables from $DAY1 to $DAY14. That bit of code obviously doesn't work, but I needed some ideas on how to make this happen. I use a loop that increments the COUNT variable like so:

```
for i in $(seq 1 14); do
  let COUNT+=1
done
```

Comment: How about using an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `eval`; it's a bad habit to get into. If you don't want to use an array, use indirect parameter expansion.

```
DAY1=$(date +"%d/%b/%Y")
DAY2=$(date --date="-1 days" +"%d/%b/%Y")
...
DAY14=$(date --date="-13 days" +"%d/%b/%Y")

COUNT=7
var="DAY$COUNT"
echo "${!var}"   # Displays the value of $COUNT7
```

Answer (score 1):

You could construct the variable expression and use *eval* to execute the command.  For example:

```
for i in {1..14}; do
  let COUNT+=1

  command=echo DAY${COUNT}
  eval $command

done
```

Another approach, that might make more sense would be to use bash arrays.

Comment: I need to pass the variables into grep, so an array would probably make more sense here.